Spring Boot Error: PKIX Path Building Failed - Unable to Find Valid Certification Path to Requested Target
this certificate is new to me in Spring Boot. I have Postman, and it successfully gets a response after I manually added the sample.key and sample.pem in the client certificate section. First, I turned off SSL certificate verification. Then, in the Client Certificate section, I set the Host to sandbox.sample.com, the CRT file to sample.pem, and the Key file to sample.key. With these settings, I got a successful response. However, when I tried to implement this in Spring Boot, I'm encountering an error.
config
    private final SslBundles sslBundles;

    @Autowired
    public RestTemplateConfig(SslBundles sslBundles) {
        this.sslBundles = sslBundles;
    }

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder, SslBundles sslBundles) {
        return builder

                .setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("client"))
                .build();
    }

application.properties
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.client.keystore.certificate=cert/sample.pem
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.client.keystore.private-key=cert/sample.key
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.bundle=client

Maven dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


Error
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://sandbox.sample.com": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] with root cause

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148) ~[na:na]


This question is similar to: "PKIX path building failed" and "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @BIBOOunit related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75774738/using-certification-as-pem-and-private-key-as-key-to-call-secured-rest-end-poi
